# I'm unable to finish ListActivity as I can't open different activities onListItemClick.How can I Invoke classes with Class.forName?

Tags: java, android

So I'm having trouble finishing a list activity.Basically the problem is that, when I click an item in list say, MainActivity nothing happens. I tried changing the name of value in array adapter but nothing seems to work. 
Is the problem with the manifest xml file?

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class Menu extends ListActivity{
    String classes[]={ "Mainactivity","Textplay","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
        }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        try
        {   
            Class myclass=Class.forName("com.hello.myproject. " +classes[position]);//Path is give to whatever list item was clicked
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Menu.this, myclass);
            startActivity(myintent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException  e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hello.myproject">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Menu">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TextPlay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.TEXTPLAY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry for wasting everyone's time. The solution was so simple.

Comment: Remove the super call.

Comment: Doesn't work. Simply moves to the emulator home screen if I click something.

Comment: Can you please suggest me an alternative? I'm kinda stuck at this for hours now and cannot move on unless I get a solution.

Comment: Where's your logcat with an error? Sure, the manifest is wrong, your Activity names in that string array do not match

Comment: Sorry for that. I had changed that but I had not edited that in the question here. Now I have put activity names that do match but still this thing won't work..:(

Comment: They still don't match. `MainActivity` has a capital A

Comment: You also have no example2 class at all

Comment: Huh. Just noticed that.Sorry for absolutely being ridiculously dumb and wasting everyone's time. I'm so f'ing stupid. I should jump off a bridge or something. I will delete this question to save embarrassment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Class[] activities`, not a string array.

Then, you don't use string concatenation, and you are guaranteed to need to have those activity classes already defined.

If you still get errors, those classes must be declared in the manifest

---

Besides, these should not be all caps `MAINACTIVITY","TEXTPLAY"`. Those aren't valid class names in your manifest.

You seem to misunderstand what the `<intent-filter>` does. You only have to define an `<activity>` tag, and it's that name value there that `startActivity` uses

Comment: I had updated the class names. Sorry for not updating it in the question. It still doesn't work though.